# Creating html dynamically in asp

Tags: c#, asp.net, htmlgenericcontrol

i want to create below html tags dynamically in asp.net

```
<div class = " class1 ">
            <a class = " class2 " href = "#">
                <img class = "class3" src = "xyz">
            </a>
        </div>
```

Comment: do you want to create them on the client or server side? What have you tried so far?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, your question doesnt really fit the Q&A style at the moment. Consider editing it to include what you've tried so far and why it doesnt work. http://stackoverflow.com/tour

Comment: Do you mean you just want to take that html and use C# to append it to some element on the web page?

Comment: For what you want to create them? For "as is" You can use StringBuilder and append html controls and finally assign to a Label's text. If you want to fetch from database, you can use databound controls like ListView, Repeater, GridView, etc. Please show your code to people here so that they can help you.

Comment: i am a beginner and i am trying to display images from database dynamically in a asp page with some css . on src i will be giving the handler with image id

Answer (score 1):

For server-side have a look at the [Literal](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.literal%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and [PlaceHolder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.placeholder%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) controls.

For client-side you could use jQuery's [append](https://api.jquery.com/append/) method